# Indexing tensors in custom loss function with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I'm using a custom loss function in `Keras`.
This is the function:

```
def custom_loss(groups_id_count):
  def listnet_loss(real_labels, predicted_labels):
    losses = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.float32) # Tensor of rank 1
    for group in groups_id_count:
      start_range = 0
      end_range = (start_range + group[1])
      batch_real_labels = tf.slice(real_labels, [start_range, 1, None], [end_range, 1, None])
      batch_predicted_labels = tf.slice(predicted_labels, [start_range, 0, 0], [end_range, 0, 0])
      loss = -K.sum(get_top_one_probability(batch_real_labels)) * tf.math.log(get_top_one_probability(batch_predicted_labels))
      losses = tf.concat([losses, loss], axis=0)
      start_range = end_range
    return K.mean(losses)
  return listnet_loss
```

I would get `real_labels`and `predicted_labels`items from `start_range` to `end_range`, but the current code returns an exception:

Error:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor.
Contents: [0, 1, None]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

I don't know what to do because it's my first experience with `TensorFlow`and `Keras`.
How can I get the items using indexing on tensor? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @pairon, Kindly provide a minimum reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of `None` `shape` specified in the `tf.placeholder` and it is occurring in the line,

```
  batch_real_labels = tf.slice(real_labels, [start_range, 1, None], [end_range, 1, None])
```

Solution for this is to define a `variable` as the `shape` of that `placeholder` and use that `variable` instead of `None`.

Code for the same is shown below:

```
h = tf.shape(losses)[0]
batch_real_labels = tf.slice(real_labels, [start_range, 1, h], [end_range, 1, h])
```

This workaround will fix the error, `TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [0, 1, None]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.` but subsequent lines of code may lead to other error.

If you face any other error, please share the `error`, complete code including the function, `get_top_one_probability` and the objective as, what exactly you want to achieve using that function, `custom_loss` and I can happily help you.

Being new to `Tensorflow` and `Keras`, I Wish you Happy Learning!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the backend function *K.reshape* to reshape both the input label and input prediction based on your own knowledge.

For the label, the input is undefined (?,?), so you need to fix it by reshaping it. Otherwise, you cannot index it.